# Should I use a dedicated user for GitLab integration?

Tags: gitlab, youtrack

YouTrack supports integration with GitLab, which I would like to use.

When I create a new integration, YouTrack asks for a private token and gives me the option to navigate to my own user profile on our GitLab server to copy my token.

Does that mean that all future actions performed by YouTrack will be performed with my user account? Should I create a separate user for YouTrack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does mean that all future actions are performed with this user, but all those actions are read-only. The only modifying action is that if you delete/disable the integration, YouTrack will delete a web hook that it registers in GitLab.

Comment: And if I connect (general) YouTrack to (my) GitLab account, is there a possibility that some other, let's say, Project or System Admin, will have access to my private repositories when linking projects to the corresponding Git repository (even if it is just read-only)?

Comment: You pass a so called GitLab Personal Access Token to YouTrack so that it can call GitLab. Generally, this token can be used to access your data via REST.

Comment: Hmm.. we misunderstood. Assume two admins/project managers of YouTrack, both having access to some project, let's say "Project Foo". Admin_One goes to /admin/editProject/[ID]?tab=vcs (VCS Integrations for project) and uses it's (Admin_One's) GitLab's Private Token to grant YouTrack access to GitLab's repository he has access to. Then second admin, Admin_Two, can go to the same place and use already set (by Admin_One) YT-GL connection to see what other repositories Admin_One has access to. Am I right? :) Couldn't the connection YT-GL be done using GitLab project's "Deploy Keys" feature?

Comment: yes, your understanding is correct. The second admin can list the repos available to the first admin.
Deploy Keys can not be used for this matter since YT needs some write access to the repository, namely it needs to be able to create a web hook so that GL pushes changes into YT.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer, Alex! :)